# How to test a Queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views

I'm quite new to Django and need help with testing my view module. Right now the view only returns all the objects from the DB:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return people.objects.all()
```

I want to test that the view returns all the objects. I know that I should use assertQuerysetEqual and I have read about it but still not sure how to implement it because I couldn't understand much from the documentation. Would appreciate it greatly if someone could show some examples or explain.

Comment: Are you trying to test what's rendered? Or some other function that returns a `people` queryset?

Comment: I want to test a function that returns a people Queryset

Answer (score 10):

Considering you are using class-based views. You can do the following steps to test `get_queryset` method. Process for testing other functions should be similer.

1. Create a request object using request factory from django.

```
from django.test import RequestFactory


request = RequestFactory().get('/view-path')
```

2. Create a view instance

```
view = YourView()
```

3. Attach request to view

```
view.request = request
```

4. Call your method and compare results.

```
qs = view.get_queryset()
```

Whole test-case would look something like this

```
def test_get_queryset(self):
    request = RequestFactory().get('/view-path')
    view = YourView()
    view.request = request

    qs = view.get_queryset()

    self.assertQuerysetEqual(qs, people.objects.all())
```